# My CSS, footer and header don't show up!

Tags: headers, css, footer

When I activate my theme in my-admin on WordPress, my CSS, header and the footer don’t show up. I really don't know what the problem is because I followed all the steps of a tutorial.

**`header.php`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title>
<?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?>
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
</title>
<!-- Main WordPress Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- WYSIWYG CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/wysiwyg.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />



<link href="<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<?php  wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topBar"></div>

<!-- Begin container -->
<div id="container">
<!-- Begin contact -->
<div class="contactInfo">
  <ul>
    <li>1234 Main Street NE, Suite 201</li>
    <li>Grand Rapids, MI 49503 Main 616 555 5555</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--/ End contact --> 

<!-- Begin navigation container -->
<div class="navigationContainer"> 

  <!-- Begin logo -->
  <div class="logo"> <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Megan Sullivan" /></a> </div>
  <!--/ End logo --> 

  <!-- Begin navigation -->
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/ End navigation --> 

</div>
<!--/ End navigation container --> 

<!-- Begin grey separator -->
<div class="greySeparator"></div>
<!--/ End grey separator -->
```

**`footer.php`**

```
 <!-- Begin footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        Copyright &copy; 2009, Megan Sullivan. All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
    <!--/ End footer -->
</div>
<!--/ End container -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what template files does your theme have? do they call `get_header()` and `get_footer()`?

Comment: Paste the contents of your `index.php` file into the question itself. Pastebins are subject to link rot. I suspect that that is where the problem is, and possibly in other files as well.

Comment: I suspect you don't have `short_open_tag` enabled. Replace `<? bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` with `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>`. If this fixes the issue, then that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your index.php and other public facing pages should be.. Don't forget to add get_header() and get_footer()

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- Row for main content area -->
    <div id="content">

        <div>
            <!--  Main Content Loop HERE, or just use while have posts and get the content;..-->
            <?php get_template_part('loop', 'index'); ?>
        </div>

    </div><!-- End Content row -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Learn more here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer